# SwiftUI how to alternate a menu item based on modifiers

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu, menuitem

In SwiftUI how to to alternate between 2 menu items, when holding down the Options key

like when you open a Finder File menu and press down the Options key, some items alternate

sadly my approach still shows both options

```
        Button("Alternative option") {
            
        }
        .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent("i"), modifiers: [.command, .option])

        Button("Regular option") {
            
        }
        .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent("i"), modifiers: [.command])
```

[image]